# Is i++ or ++i better for this program?

Tags: c++, string, function, for-loop, integer

i'm trying to create a program which checks if input is is an int or a string.

This is the code:

```
// CPP program to check if a given string 
// is a valid integer 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
  
// Returns true if s is a number else false 
bool isNumber(string s) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
        if (isdigit(s[i]) == false) 
            return false; 
  
    return true; 
} 
  
// Driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    // Saving the input in a string 
    string str = "6790"; 
  
    // Function returns 1 if all elements 
    // are in range '0-9' 
    if (isNumber(str)) 
        cout << "Integer"; 
  
    // Function returns 0 if the input is 
    // not an integer 
    else
        cout << "String"; 
}
```

I wanted to ask that whether i++ or ++i is better for this loop and why?

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
        if (isdigit(s[i]) == false) 
            return false;
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: The input is always a string. The question is whether the **text** in that string can be **converted** to an integer. Don't lose sight of that distinction. If you do, sooner or later you'll get bitten badly.

Comment: Also, be very careful about testing the return values from the C-style classification functions (`isdigit` in this example). They return an **integer**; 0 means the test failed, and non-zero means it succeeded. `if (isdigit(s[i] == false)` will work, because `false` converts to 0. But if you need to go the other way, `if (isdigit(s[i] == true)` won't necessarily work. `true` converts to 1, but the function is not required to return 1, and often will return some other value. To check this reliably, let the compiler do the work: `if (!isdigit(s[i]))` and `if (isdigit(s[i]))` will work reliably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the form `++i` in C++, because `i` may be an iterator or other object with overloaded `operator++`. In those cases, the form `i++` generates a temporary object to hold the previous value of `i`, while the form `++i` does not. The compiler may optimize away that temporary object, but it’s not required to, and in some cases may not be allowed to.

So, `++i` is slightly better than `i++` as the former need not retain the initial value and recheck it. It is one of the very few instances where time optimization and memory optimization occur simultaneously. But the difference is too small to be noted, just 4 bytes. Also, the time difference is negligibly small.

You would essentially get the same answer in your example but might receive a minute time and memory optimization while using `++i`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the datatype of i is int, it doesn't matter if you use i++ or ++i.
If its a large class iterator, ++i is faster than i++. Its a good practice to use ++i.

Comment: thanks! can you tell me what's the difference  between ++i and i++?

Comment: @AustinParker `++i` increments `i`, then uses `i`. `i++` uses `i`, then increments. Here it doesn't matter which order you use, because you aren't using `i` in that statement, but there may be some performance advantages in some cases to pre-increment. The thing is if you know that trick, odds are the compiler does too.